# What is the time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I believe that the following code has time complexity O(n), while my friend believes that it has complexity O(n^3).

Edit: n being the number of elements in data

```
var hash = {}
for (var element in data) {
  var k1
  var k2
  var k3
  // ... stuff
  if (!hash[k1]) {
    hash[k1] = {}
  }
  if (!hash[k1][k2]) {
    hash[k1][k2] = {}
  }
  if (!hash[k1][k2][k3]) {
    hash[k1][k2][k3] = 0
  }
  hash[k1][k2][k3] = hash[k1][k2][k3] + 1
}

for (var k1 in hash) {
  for (var k2 in hash[k1]) {
    for (var k3 in hash[k1][k2]) {
      // really do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

What is the time complexity for that algorithm?

Edit: n being the number of elements in data

Edit:
So, my friend's reasoning that it is O(n^3) is because of the triple loop.
My reasoning is that even with the triple loop, it is exhaustive over the hash and no more. Each element in hash is basically indexed by a 3-tuple, (k1, k2, k3). While normally traversing over a 3 deep loop would be O(n^3), I believe that each level of the hash functions as a sparse array, and by that I mean that adding to a hash would not affect other hashes on the same level, or even other hashes on the other levels.

Comment: This probably belongs to code review

Comment: What's `n`? Also, why don't you include your analysis that shows the code is `O(n)` (and perhaps also your friend's)?

Comment: I think that the "stuff" you left out is the key to understanding this.  Also here you can use these for free as I've got lots of extras: `; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;`

Answer (score 0):

I used a proof for how it is a tree structure and used the general inductive proof for trees to show that it was O(n)